# OCMockito - Verify order of method invocations

Tags: ios, objective-c, tdd, ocmockito

As far as I can see, there is no way to verify the order of method invocations on a mock.
Or am I missing something?

```
- (void)testResetCameraState_resetsCameraView
{
   // Arrange
   [given([_cameraManagerMock previewLayer]) willReturn:_testLayer];

   // Act
   [_cameraInteractor resetCameraState];

   // Assert
   [verifyCount(_cameraViewMock, times(1)) resetPreview];
   [verifyCount(_cameraViewMock, times(1)) setPreviewLayer:_testLayer];
}
```

In this case you cannot verify, that the `setPreviewLayer:` is called after `resetPreview`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.
It's based on the `givenVoid` method added in this pull request:
https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito/pull/93

Sadly it is not merged yet, so you need to download and build this version by yourself:
https://github.com/lysannschlegel/OCMockito/tree/given_void

With the new method you can verify the order of method calls in the following way:

```
- (void)testResetCameraState_resetsCameraView
{
    // Arrange
    [given([_cameraManagerMock previewLayer]) willReturn:_testLayer];
    [givenVoid([self->_cameraViewMock resetPreview]) willDo:^id (NSInvocation *invocation)
     {
         [(MKTBaseMockObject*)self->_cameraViewMock reset];
         return nil;
     }];

    // Act
    [_cameraInteractor resetCameraState];

    // Assert
    [verifyCount(_cameraViewMock, never()) resetPreview];
    [verifyCount(_cameraViewMock, times(1)) setPreviewLayer:_testLayer];
}
```

This will reset the mock after the first call of `resetPreview`.
So we can verify stuff after that call:

1. `resetPreview` is never called after the first call.
2. `setPreviewLayer` is called after resetPreview.

The `reset` call also resets the `givenVoid() willDo:` so a second `reset` call wouldn't reset the mock again.

Hope this helps, happy coding :D